# How do I accomplish a VLOOKUP if my key range is discontinuous?

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

So, I've got a chart (an EXP chart for an RPG) with several break points in it. One column is how many EXP is required to get to a level, the other column is what level you get to be given that EXP total. Like this:

```
  EXP | Level
---------------
    0 | 1
2,000 | 2
4,000 | 3
9,000 | 4
```

and it goes up to level 36, but you get the idea. The EXP required does *not* follow a formula (sadly).

Now, I want the player to type into one box how many EXP they have, and then I want another box to reference the chart and compute their current level. I know that I could do it using a long chain of if statements, but it seems like there should be a better way of doing it.

What is that better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better way is to use [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?rd=1).

`=VLOOKUP(D1,A2:B37,2)`

Comment: Oh, you're right it doesn't have to be an exact match after all. Now I feel stupid for not just trying it out.